# Error while using using phpGraphlib Library

Tags: php, graph, shared-libraries

I m using phpgraphlibrary in my php project to create barchart but when i try to run the program it shows only the blank image

[image]

Program

```
<?php
include("phpgraphlib.php");
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(400,300);
$data = array("Alex"=>99, "Mary"=>98, "Joan"=>70, "Ed"=>90);
$graph->addData($data);
$graph->setTitle("Test Scores");
$graph->setTextColor("blue");
$graph->createGraph();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a solution for this, but I have discovered something that may help us come up with a solution. I have been having the same problem. My local server is running PHP v.7.1.6. PHPGraphLib will not render the graph if the data array is an associative array. It will however render the graph if it is a numeric array. It appears that some internal representation of associative arrays in PHP 7.1 is different than PHP 5. My web host is running PHP 5.4.45, and it renders the graph flawlessly WITH the associative array. I am looking now to see if I can find out what has changed about associative arrays in PHP 7.1.